# xamarin forms droid resource not found errors

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

Please help me I am getting lots of resource errors

```
'Resource.Attribute' does not contain a definition for 

'mediaRouteSettingsDrawable'    
'Resource.Color' does not contain a definition for 'design_textinput_error_color'   
'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'design_fab_content_size'    
'Resource.Dimension' does not contain a definition for 'design_navigation_padding_top_default'
```

Like this I have 150 errors not sure what is causing this. If I delete them from Resource.Designer it emulator starts in the next build it again comes with all the errors.

Please help me.

Comment: Try using free internet (proxy free), and get the fresh needed packages .
rebuild and u will have ur way

Comment: I don't have any proxy, I tried all sorts of things but no use

Comment: its related to the package ur using , those might be outdated ,or could be latest version which xamarin forms doesn't support .

put ur prroject folder upload it at github ,incase u want me to fix it \

Comment: Found it. The issue is with ffimageloading which is not working with new version of xamarin  forms. Need to remove it and find an alternative for that. Thanks for offering help to fix it.

Comment: Post this answer , this might help other guys !

Comment: @saketkumar could you please help me with this http://stackoverflow.com/q/37289517

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue the problem is with the FFImageLoading package which is causing issues with new version of Xamarin forms

Comment: Can you explain what the problem actually was? I am having the exact same issue where another library is giving the same 151 errors.

Comment: The library is assigning some native resources to resources in the control which are not available that's why I removed that library and implemented my own caching